# R: how to check if vector elements are the same

Tags: r

```
> dput(ranks)
structure(c(NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 1L), .Names = c("LANG1", 
"LANG2", "LANG3", "LANG4", "LANG5", "LANG6", "LANG7", "LANG8", 
"LANG9"))
> ranks
LANG1 LANG2 LANG3 LANG4 LANG5 LANG6 LANG7 LANG8 LANG9 
   NA    NA     2     2    NA    NA    NA     2     1
```

I have a vector with 9 elements in it, and I want to check if all the elements in that vector are the same. Usually I just use `all(ranks == ranks[1])`, but in this case since the first element is an `NA`, I don't get a TRUE/FALSE output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply check the number of unique values:

```
length(unique(ranks)) == 1
```