# how to identify the row numbers having same value for all column in R?

Tags: r, duplicates, rows

For the following data

```
> data
   x1 x2 x3
1   1  0  0
2   0  1  0
3   0  0  1
4   1  0  1
5   1  0  0
6   0  1  1
7   1  0  0
8   0  1  0
9   1  1  1
10  1  0  0
```

How can I identify which rows have the same value across all column. For `data`, row number `4`  and `6` has same value for column `1 & 3` and `2 & 3` respectively  and row number `9` has same value for all column. How can identify these row numbers in R. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more general solution would be to use @zero33's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910427/r-how-to-check-if-vector-elements-are-the-same) and do

```
> bool <- apply(data, 1, function(row) length(unique(row)) == 1)
> bool
##     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10 
## FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

You can use that boolean vector to identify what rows have the same value in all columns using

```
> data <- data[bool, ]
#   x1 x2 x3
# 9  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 6):

Also an option is to check variance of each row. A row with 0 variance have all the values as same

```
data[apply(data, 1, var) == 0, ]
#  x1 x2 x3
#9  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have values that can only be 0 or 1 and you want to look for rows having the same value in ALL columns, you have to look for either 0 or the length of your columns:

```r
df <- data[c(rowSums(data) == 0,rowSums(data) == length(data)),]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `sweep` and `rowSums`:

```
data[rowSums(sweep(data[, -1L], 1L, data[, 1L], `==`)) == ncol(data) - 1L, ]
```

output:

```
  x1 x2 x3
9  1  1  1
```

data:

```
data <- read.table(text="x1 x2 x3
1  0  0
0  1  0
0  0  1
1  0  1
1  0  0
0  1  1
1  0  0
0  1  0
1  1  1
1  0  0", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another approach with `rowSums`

```
data[!rowSums(data[,1] != data[,-1]),]
```